# Unity Raycasting a tag rather than layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have made a game where I use raycasting to determine whether or not the player is on an object. I know how to do this using layers, but I'd rather make it so it checks if it hits an object with a tag. Heres the code:

```
  isObject = Physics2D.Linecast (this.transform.position, groundedEnd.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Object"));
```

So rather than comparing to a layermask with the name "Object", I would rather it checked if it hits an object with a tag, but I do not know what to replace LayerMask with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
 RaycastHit2D h = Physics2D.Linecast(p1, p2);
 if(h.collider.tag == "YOUR_TAG")
 {
     //Do your stuff
 }
```

Comment: That did not seem to work, it did not recognize that I hit the object with that tag. Is there no way of replacing the "<<LayerMask.NameToLayer" part with a tag method of some kind?

Comment: No. The ability to filter objects for raycasting with layers comes from the fact that there's a limited amount of layers, which allows unity to keep a convenient data structure (I assume) to filter it. However, you can have as many tags as you want, which would defeat the optimisation purpose of this data structure.

Comment: you also can use `OnCollisionEnter2D` Event to detect 2D collisions

Answer (score 1):

Don't have experience with 2D raycasting but checking the tag of a raycasted hit object in 3D is this, maybe you can change it a bit for it to apply to 2D:

```
RaycastHit raycastHit;
if(Physicas.Raycast(from, to , out raycastHit, maxDistance)){
Collider = raycastHitCollider = raycastHit.collider;
    if (raycastHitCollider.gameObject.tag == "Your tag here"){
    //do stuff
    }
}
```